# How to test camel route that only set properties

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a route builder that depending on the content of a message sets specific properties. It doesn't send it to other endpoints so I cannot mock them and check what they got.
I can produce a message or exchange but is there a way to check it after it was transformed by this route builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your route is synchronous (i.e. not `from:seda`), you can simply check that the property was updated on the exchange that you send via the `ProducerTemplate`.

Let's assume that you need to check the value of the property `TestProp`:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.ExchangeBuilder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
class PropertyUpdateTest {
    @Produce("direct:testProps")
    ProducerTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    void verifyRouteUpdatesProperty() {
        Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
                .withProperty("TestProp", "InitialVal")
                .build();

        template.send(exchange);

        assertThat(exchange.getProperty("TestProp")).isEqualTo("UpdatedVal");
    }

}
```